# embedded jetty unable to parse web.xml when jsp jars present in classpath

Tags: jsp, jetty

I'm getting the following error when starting my app as embedded jetty:

```
Exception initializing TldLocationsCache: XML parsing error on file /WEB-INF/web.xml: (line 2, col 9): Document is invalid: no grammar found.
```

My web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app 
   xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
version="3.0">
<welcome-file-list>
 <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

Startup code:

```
    Server server = new Server(8080);

    WebAppContext context = new WebAppContext();

    context.setResourceBase("WebContent");
    context.setDescriptor("/WEB-INF/web.xml");

    context.setContextPath("/" + "test");
    context.setParentLoaderPriority(false);

    server.setHandler(context);

    server.start();
    server.join();
```

When trying to narrow down the problem I noticed that this happens when I add the jsp related jars to the classpath. Without those jars I don't get this error.

```
lib/jsp:
javax.el-3.0.0.jar                jetty-jsp-9.2.10.v20150310.jar
javax.servlet.jsp-2.3.2.jar       jetty-jsp-jdt-2.3.3.jar
javax.servlet.jsp-api-2.3.1.jar   org.eclipse.jdt.core-3.8.2.v20130121.jar
javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-1.2.2.jar
org.eclipse.jetty.orbit.javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-1.2.0.v201105211821.jar

lib/apache-jsp:
org.eclipse.jetty.apache-jsp-9.2.10.v20150310.jar
org.eclipse.jetty.orbit.org.eclipse.jdt.core-3.8.2.v20130121.jar
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Embedded jetty webserver JSP support not configured](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28483277/embedded-jetty-webserver-jsp-support-not-configured)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That startup code in your question is woefully insufficient to setup a webapp for JSP.

See prior answer: [Embedded jetty webserver JSP support not configured](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28483277/embedded-jetty-webserver-jsp-support-not-configured/28483349#28483349)

Comment: Thanks, I updated the code as prescribed in the example. I hit another wall that I'm describing here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29613569/java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-javax-servlet-jsp-tagext-tagattributeinfo-with-embe