# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.jsp.tagext.TagAttributeInfo with embedded jetty with jsp support

Tags: jsp, jetty

Per instructions found in here [embedded jetty unable to parse web.xml when jsp jars present in classpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29572781/embedded-jetty-unable-to-parse-web-xml-when-jsp-jars-present-in-classpath/29584588#29584588)
I put together the following startup code to launch jetty with jsp support in embedded mode but still having no luck. I'm gettign the following error, full stack provided farther below:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.jsp.tagext.TagAttributeInfo.<init>(Ljava/lang/String;ZLjava/lang/String;ZZLjava/lang/String;ZZLjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)V
```

The class in question, javax.servlet.jsp.tagext.TagAttributeInfo, is defined in org.mortbay.jasper.apache-jsp-8.0.9.M3.jar. This jar is also required for other reason, to bring in the class JasperInitializer, superclass of JettyJasperInitializer.

I'm suspecting that using the jar org.mortbay.jasper.apache-jsp-8.0.9.M3.jar is not recommended for jetty 9.2.10.v20150310. If so - what's the alternative?
Wher should I get org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperInitializer and javax.servlet.jsp.tagext.TagAttributeInfo?

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.jsp.tagext.TagAttributeInfo.<init>(Ljava/lang/String;ZLjava/lang/String;ZZLjava/lang/String;ZZLjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)V
at org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.tld.TldRuleSet$Attribute.toTagAttributeInfo(TldRuleSet.java:272)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.tld.TldRuleSet$TagAttributeRule.end(TldRuleSet.java:150)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.endElement(Digester.java:959)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.dtd.XMLNSDTDValidator.endNamespaceScope(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.handleEndElement(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.endElement(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanEndElement(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1457)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.tld.TldParser.parse(TldParser.java:76)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.parseTld(TldScanner.java:257)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldPreScanned.scanJars(TldPreScanned.java:46)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scan(TldScanner.java:99)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperInitializer.onStartup(JasperInitializer.java:103)
at org.eclipse.jetty.plus.annotation.ContainerInitializer.callStartup(ContainerInitializer.java:140)
at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.ServletContainerInitializersStarter.doStart(ServletContainerInitializersStarter.java:65)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:274)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1349)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1342)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:741)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:505)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:387)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:354)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
at webappdev.JettyWebAppTest.init(JettyWebAppTest.java:140)
at webappdev.JettyWebAppTest.main(JettyWebAppTest.java:148)
```

My startup code:

```java
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
 {
    JettyWebAppTest thiss = new JettyWebAppTest();
    thiss.init();
 }


private void init() throws Exception {

    System.setProperty("java.io.tmpdir", "/tmp/bolek");
    System.setProperty("org.apache.jasper.compiler.disablejsr199", "false");
    Server server = new Server(8080);

    WebAppContext context = new WebAppContext();

    context.setResourceBase(<myresourcebase>);
    context.setDescriptor("/WEB-INF/web.xml");

    context.setContextPath("/");
    context.setParentLoaderPriority(false);
    context.setAttribute(
     "org.eclipse.jetty.server.webapp.ContainerIncludeJarPattern",
       ".*/[^/]*servlet-api-[^/]*\\.jar$|.*/javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-.*\\.jar$|.*/.*taglibs.*\\.jar$");


    context.setAttribute("javax.servlet.context.tempdir", 
            System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir"));

    context.setAttribute("org.eclipse.jetty.containerInitializers",
         this.jspInitializers());
    context.setAttribute(InstanceManager.class.getName(),
            new SimpleInstanceManager());
    context.addBean(new ServletContainerInitializersStarter(context),
          true);

    context.setClassLoader(this.getUrlClassLoader());

    context.addServlet(this.jspServletHolder(), "*.jsp");


    server.setHandler(context);

    server.start();
    server.join();      
 }


 private ServletHolder defaultServletHolder(URI baseUri)
{
    ServletHolder holderDefault = new ServletHolder("default",
          DefaultServlet.class);

    holderDefault.setInitParameter("resourceBase", 
        baseUri.toASCIIString());
    holderDefault.setInitParameter("dirAllowed", "true");
    return holderDefault;
}


 private List<ContainerInitializer> jspInitializers()
 {
    JettyJasperInitializer sci = new JettyJasperInitializer();
    ServletContainerInitializer scii;
    scii = (ServletContainerInitializer)sci;

    ContainerInitializer initializer = new ContainerInitializer(scii, null);
    List<ContainerInitializer> initializers = new ArrayList<ContainerInitializer>();
    initializers.add(initializer);
    return initializers;
 }


 private ClassLoader getUrlClassLoader()
 {
    ClassLoader jspClassLoader = new URLClassLoader(new URL[0], this.getClass().getClassLoader());
    return jspClassLoader;
 }




private ServletHolder jspServletHolder()
{
    ServletHolder holderJsp = new ServletHolder("jsp", JettyJspServlet.class);
    holderJsp.setInitOrder(0);
    holderJsp.setInitParameter("logVerbosityLevel", "DEBUG");
    holderJsp.setInitParameter("fork", "false");
    holderJsp.setInitParameter("xpoweredBy", "false");
    holderJsp.setInitParameter("compilerTargetVM", "1.7");
    holderJsp.setInitParameter("compilerSourceVM", "1.7");
    holderJsp.setInitParameter("keepgenerated", "true");
    return holderJsp;
}
```

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app 
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
version="3.0">
 <welcome-file-list>
  <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
 </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have conflicting jars.

The files in the distro's `lib/jsp` are for the Glassfish Implementation of JSP.

The Glassfish Implementation is now deprecated (due to amount of bugs and lack up updates from the implementors), and has been fully removed in the upcoming Jetty 9.3 release.

Do not include these Glassfish Implementation jars with your project.

Only use the 4 jars in the distro's `lib/apache-jsp/` directory, this is the Apache Jasper JSP implementation.

The Apache Jasper JSP implementation is fully supported, stable, up to date, and has an active and healthy community and developer base.

Comment: Getting java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.ServletContext.getJspConfigDescriptor()Ljavax/servlet/descriptor/JspConfigDescriptor;. This method does not appear to be defined anywhere in jetty distro.

Comment: Continuing the struggle here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29615909/java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-javax-servlet-servletcontext-getjspconfigdescriptor