# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.ServletContext.getJspConfigDescriptor using embedded jetty with jsp

Tags: jsp, jetty

I'm trying to use jetty in embedded mode. I'm getting the following error on initialization:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.ServletContext.getJspConfigDescriptor()Ljavax/servlet/descriptor/JspConfigDescriptor;
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJspConfig(TldScanner.java:148)
```

Searched all the jars that ship with jetty 9.2.10.v20150310 but none but the class in question, javax.servlet.ServletContext, is not defined anywhere. Only interface in servlet-api-3.1.jar

My startup code:

```java
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
 {
    JettyWebAppTest thiss = new JettyWebAppTest();
    thiss.init();
 }


private void init() throws Exception {

    System.setProperty("java.io.tmpdir", "/tmp/bolek");
    System.setProperty("org.apache.jasper.compiler.disablejsr199", "false");
    Server server = new Server(8080);

    WebAppContext context = new WebAppContext();

    context.setResourceBase(<myresourcebase>);
    context.setDescriptor("/WEB-INF/web.xml");

    context.setContextPath("/");
    context.setParentLoaderPriority(false);
    context.setAttribute(
     "org.eclipse.jetty.server.webapp.ContainerIncludeJarPattern",
       ".*/[^/]*servlet-api-[^/]*\\.jar$|.*/javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-.*\\.jar$|.*/.*taglibs.*\\.jar$");


    context.setAttribute("javax.servlet.context.tempdir", 
            System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir"));

    context.setAttribute("org.eclipse.jetty.containerInitializers",
         this.jspInitializers());
    context.setAttribute(InstanceManager.class.getName(),
            new SimpleInstanceManager());
    context.addBean(new ServletContainerInitializersStarter(context),
          true);

    context.setClassLoader(this.getUrlClassLoader());

    context.addServlet(this.jspServletHolder(), "*.jsp");


    server.setHandler(context);

    server.start();
    server.join();      
 }


 private ServletHolder defaultServletHolder(URI baseUri)
{
    ServletHolder holderDefault = new ServletHolder("default",
          DefaultServlet.class);

    holderDefault.setInitParameter("resourceBase", 
        baseUri.toASCIIString());
    holderDefault.setInitParameter("dirAllowed", "true");
    return holderDefault;
}


 private List<ContainerInitializer> jspInitializers()
 {
    JettyJasperInitializer sci = new JettyJasperInitializer();
    ServletContainerInitializer scii;
    scii = (ServletContainerInitializer)sci;

    ContainerInitializer initializer = new ContainerInitializer(scii, null);
    List<ContainerInitializer> initializers = new ArrayList<ContainerInitializer>();
    initializers.add(initializer);
    return initializers;
 }


 private ClassLoader getUrlClassLoader()
 {
    ClassLoader jspClassLoader = new URLClassLoader(new URL[0], this.getClass().getClassLoader());
    return jspClassLoader;
 }




private ServletHolder jspServletHolder()
{
    ServletHolder holderJsp = new ServletHolder("jsp", JettyJspServlet.class);
    holderJsp.setInitOrder(0);
    holderJsp.setInitParameter("logVerbosityLevel", "DEBUG");
    holderJsp.setInitParameter("fork", "false");
    holderJsp.setInitParameter("xpoweredBy", "false");
    holderJsp.setInitParameter("compilerTargetVM", "1.7");
    holderJsp.setInitParameter("compilerSourceVM", "1.7");
    holderJsp.setInitParameter("keepgenerated", "true");
    return holderJsp;
}
```

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app 
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
version="3.0">
 <welcome-file-list>
  <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
 </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some incompatible, older version/s of the servlet api on your classpath. Try printing out the classpath from each of the classloaders in the hierarchy. Also investigate your startup setup to see which jars are being put on the runtime classpath.

Jan

Answer (score 0):

In Java Build Path/Libraries/Groovy Library specify "No" to the inclusion of all jars from Groovy lib folder.

Make this change and "finish".

[Groovy Libraries Dialog Box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gULyf.png)

Note: if you bring up this dialog box again, you will still see the "yes" selected. Ignore that.