# Application with embedded Jetty showing "page not found" if launched as jar

Tags: java, jar, jetty, embedded-jetty

I have an application that uses embedded jetty. When I run this application in Netbeans IDE then I can browse my site @ localhost:8080/

When I launch the jar file of my application from command line: java -jar app.jar then browsing localhost:8080/ jetty server says "*page not found*"

What am I missing here? Can't figure out the problem.

**EDIT**:

Netbeans project is uploaded to [Github](https://github.com/lkallas/embedded-jetty-jsp-jstl)

Everything works fine if I run this project in Netbeans.
But when I take the jar file with *lib* folder and run it in cmd like this: **java -jar EmbeddedJettyJspJstl.jar**

Then navigating to http://localhost:8080/test I get errors:

***org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jstl_jsp***

***org.apache.jasper.JasperException: The absolute uri: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application***

My JSP page uses JSTL and looks like it is not locating the *jstl* libraries?

And this is the code that starts the server:

```
package server;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.management.ManagementFactory;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.net.URL;

import org.eclipse.jetty.jmx.MBeanContainer;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Handler;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AllowSymLinkAliasChecker;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.DefaultHandler;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerList;
import org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.Configuration;
import org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

/**
 *
 * @author lkallas
 */
public class JettyServer {

    // Resource path pointing to where the WEBROOT is
    private static final String WEBROOT = "/webapp/";
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JettyServer.class);

    public void start() throws IOException, InterruptedException, URISyntaxException {

        Server server = new Server();

        // HTTP connector
        ServerConnector connector = new ServerConnector(server);
        connector.setHost("localhost");
        connector.setPort(8080);
        connector.setIdleTimeout(30000);

        // Set the connector
        server.addConnector(connector);

        // Setup JMX for web applications
        MBeanContainer mbContainer = new MBeanContainer(
                ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer());
        server.addBean(mbContainer);

        //Setting up web application
        WebAppContext webapp = new WebAppContext();
        webapp.setAttribute("javax.servlet.context.tempdir", getScratchDir());
        webapp.setDescriptor(WEBROOT + "WEB-INF/web.xml");
        webapp.setResourceBase(getWebRootResourceUri().toASCIIString());
        webapp.setContextPath("/");
        webapp.setWar(getWebRootResourceUri().toASCIIString());
        webapp.addAliasCheck(new AllowSymLinkAliasChecker());

        //For debugging
        logger.info("Descriptor file: {}", webapp.getDescriptor());
        logger.info("Resource base: {}", getWebRootResourceUri().toASCIIString());
        logger.info("WAR location: {}", webapp.getWar());

        HandlerList handlerList = new HandlerList();
        handlerList.setHandlers(new Handler[]{webapp, new DefaultHandler()});

        // This webapp will use jsps and jstl. We need to enable the
        // AnnotationConfiguration in order to correctly
        // set up the jsp container
        Configuration.ClassList classlist = Configuration.ClassList
                .setServerDefault(server);
        classlist.addBefore(
                "org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.JettyWebXmlConfiguration",
                "org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration");

        // Set the ContainerIncludeJarPattern so that jetty examines these
        // container-path jars for tlds, web-fragments etc.
        // If you omit the jar that contains the jstl .tlds, the jsp engine will
        // scan for them instead.
        webapp.setAttribute("org.eclipse.jetty.server.webapp.ContainerIncludeJarPattern", ".*/[^/]*taglibs.*\\.jar$");

        // A WebAppContext is a ContextHandler as well so it needs to be set to
        // the server so it is aware of where to send the appropriate requests.
        server.setHandler(handlerList);

        try {
            server.start();

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }

        server.dumpStdErr();

    }

    /**
     * Establish Scratch directory for the servlet context (used by JSP
     * compilation)
     */
    private File getScratchDir() throws IOException {
        File tempDir = new File(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir"));
        File scratchDir = new File(tempDir.toString(), "embedded-jetty");

        if (!scratchDir.exists()) {
            if (!scratchDir.mkdirs()) {
                throw new IOException("Unable to create scratch directory: " + scratchDir);
            }
        }
        return scratchDir;
    }

    /**
     * Get webroot URI.
     *
     * @return
     * @throws FileNotFoundException
     * @throws URISyntaxException
     */
    private URI getWebRootResourceUri() throws FileNotFoundException, URISyntaxException {
        URL indexUri = this.getClass().getResource(WEBROOT);
        if (indexUri == null) {
            throw new FileNotFoundException("Unable to find resource " + WEBROOT);
        }
        logger.debug("WEBROOT: {}", indexUri.toURI().toASCIIString());
        return indexUri.toURI();
    }

}
```

I have already looked @ http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/advanced-embedding.html

Comment: I think context path is missing in URL . can you post your configuration of Jetty.

Comment: I provided the source code. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a number of reasons and causes that could be affecting you.

However you haven't posted any code to help us identify what the specific cause is.

The Jetty Project maintains an example for this setup, btw.

https://github.com/jetty-project/embedded-jetty-uber-jar

Pay attention to your `context.setContextPath()` (like @Haider-Ali pointed out), and also your `context.setBaseResource()`

For JSPs in Embedded Jetty you can look at the other example project

https://github.com/jetty-project/embedded-jetty-jsp

Note [prior answer about Embedded Jetty and JSP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28483349/775715).

Comment: I provided the source code and gihub repository.
If you could help sorting this problem out it would help alot. Thank you!

Comment: Wow, JSP, yeah, that requires **a lot more work** for embedded-jetty.

Comment: Did everyhing the same way as shown in Github, still not working. The same error persists. Also tried to use different jstl jars. Jstl is just not working with embedded jetty application that is packaged to jar.
I have to drop jstl and use the old jsp style. JSP without jstl is working.