# Servlet Mappings Jetty 8

Tags: servlets, web-applications, jetty, web.xml, servlet-mapping

I have a webapp that works with Tomcat 8 and Jetty 8. Recently, we have introduced servlet-mappings

```
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>page</servlet-name>
        <jsp-file>/Dashboard.html</jsp-file>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

   <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>page</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/editjob</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

When you put an url with "http://localhost:8080/app/editjob", in tomcat is redirected to "http://localhost:8080/app/Dashboard.html". But when we deploy it using embed Jetty, a 404 Not Found  it is being returned. It seems that the servlet-mapping is not working.

```
HTTP ERROR 404
Problem accessing /app/page. Reason:
Not Found
Powered by Jetty://
```

I can enter in the app by using directly 
http://localhost:8080/app/Dashboard.html. Without mappings, we have no problem with jetty
This is the code for embedding Jetty:

```
final Server server = new Server();
SocketConnector connector = new SocketConnector();
connector.setMaxIdleTime(-1);
connector.setSoLingerTime(-1);
connector.setPort(8080);
server.setConnectors(new Connector[]{connector});
final WebAppContext context = new WebAppContext();
context.setServer(server);
context.setContextPath("app");
context.setWar(location.toExternalForm());
server.setHandler(context);
context.start();  
server.join();
```

This is the web.xml with the mappings.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
<display-name>app</display-name>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>ServletAdaptor</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ServletAdaptor</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/webresources/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
     <servlet>
        <servlet-name>login</servlet-name>
        <jsp-file>/Login.html</jsp-file>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>page</servlet-name>
        <jsp-file>/Dashboard.html</jsp-file>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        30
    </session-timeout>
</session-config>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>context</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderServlet
    </servlet-class>
</servlet> 
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/beans.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<filter>
    <filter-name>CORS</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.thetransactioncompany.cors.CORSFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.allowGenericHttpRequests</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.allowOrigin</param-name>
        <param-value>*</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.allowSubdomains</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.supportedMethods</param-name>
        <param-value>GET, POST, HEAD, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.supportedHeaders</param-name>
        <param-value>Origin, Content-Type, X-Requested-With, Access-Control-Allow-Origin</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.supportsCredentials</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.maxAge</param-name>
        <param-value>-1</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CORS</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>login</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/login</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>page</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/home</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>page</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/jobs</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

   <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>Index.html</welcome-file>

</welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

I have tried to define the servlet-mappings when i start the server, but did not work.
This mappings are working perfectly with Tomcat, but Jetty...I dont know which could be the problem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Problem accessing /app/page.
```

That URL is not mapped anywhere in your pasted `web.xml`

The servlets with urls patterns (defined in `<servlet-mapping>` entries) are:

- `/webresources/*`
- `/login`
- `/home`
- `/jobs`

None of those will match on a request URL of `/page`, resulting in the DefaultServlet (which is default mapped at `/`) returning a 404 for that requested resource.

Also, you haven't setup JSP in your `embedded-jetty` environment, so no JSP is being used.

*Copied from prior answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/28483349/775715*

If that code snippet represents how you are initializing your webapp, then you are missing **a lot** of JSP initialization steps.

There's an example project produced by the Jetty Project showing how to use JSP with embedded Jetty at

https://github.com/jetty-project/embedded-jetty-jsp

Pay attention to ...

- The dependencies you need
- The required ClassLoader type
- The scratchDir declaration
- The ServletContainerInitializer setup
- The Jsp Servlet Holder and mappings
- The InstanceManager

(just to name a few big ones)

Comment: Maybe i have a bad understanding of the servlet-mappings behavior. What i want is to redirect a lot of urls to one HTML. For that purpose i use      <jsp-file>, but i dont really want JSPs, just only redirect to the html. Perhaps i dont need jsp, and im using the web.xml in the wrong way.

Comment: If im not wrong "/app/page" is mapped, is not? I have a servlet mapping with the pattern "/editjob/", that redirects to the servlet named "page". This servlet points to <jsp-file>/Dashboard.html</jsp-file>       Many thanks for your interest!!!

Comment: If that's what you want, then declare a `<servlet-mapping>` that will capture the `url-pattern` you are interested in.  Just be careful to not capture too much, otherwise you'll be on the hook to also send static content (css, images, javascript, etc...) yourself (something jetty is very good at, if you let it)

Comment: Okey, i declare a servlet-mapping that captures "/app/page", but i need a to redirect it to a Servlet with a html associated. In that case, have i use a servlet with the tag <jsp-file>file.html</jsp-file>? Why should i use JSP if i only want to redirect to a html?

Comment: That's not how servlets or the `<jsp-file>` element work.  JSPs are just source versions of an eventual Servlet (compiled at runtime).  using `<jsp-file>` says that your servlet is based on a JSP.   Since HTML cannot be a servlet, using HTML in that element is an error.  *inside* your servlet you can redirect to HTML using the `RequestDispatcher` with `forward` or `include`.  But why? just reference the HTML directly.

Comment: Do you mean at the web.xml? Reference the html directly how? In a <servlet> tag? in a servlet-mapping tag?

Comment: I'll explain myself. I have tried to create a java Servlet class for redirecting html with forward. But i have not seen any example in which a servlet and a servlet mapping are defined at the web.xml, and redirects to html. Except the one that uses    <jsp-file>/index.jsp</jsp-file>